# How do I generate scatterplots for abundance and a numerical variable with a phyloseq object?

Tags: correlation, phyloseq

I have a phyloseq object in R, and I would like to generate scatterplots to show associations between individual taxa and a numeric variable that's in my sample data (i.e. my variable on x axis, abundance of particular taxa on y axis).
I guess I need to make some sort of loop function, but I'm a bit stuck on how to get started with this!

Answer (score 1):

See below for a `tidyverse` solution. I used the `GlobalPatterns` data from `phyloseq` to create a reproducible example. I haven't got enough reputation to post images, but the [output should look like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rgYVj.png)

```r
require("phyloseq")
require("tidyverse")

# Load the data
data(GlobalPatterns)

# Create a continuous x-variable
sample_data(GlobalPatterns)$Variable <- rnorm(nsamples(GlobalPatterns))

# select a single taxon from 
set.seed(1)
taxon <- sample(taxa_names(GlobalPatterns), size = 1)

# Function that create a scatterplot between a continuous variable (x)
# and the abundance of a taxon (y)
physeq_scatter_plot <- function(ps, variable, taxon){
  
  # Subset to taxon
  ps <- prune_taxa(x = ps, taxa = taxon)
  
  # Convert to long data format
  psdf <- psmelt(ps)
  
  # Plot
  psdf %>%
    ggplot(aes_string(x = variable,
                      y = "Abundance")) +
    geom_point()
}

physeq_scatter_plot(ps = GlobalPatterns, variable = "Variable", taxon = taxon)
#> Warning in prune_taxa(taxa, phy_tree(x)): prune_taxa attempted to reduce tree to 1 or fewer tips.
#>  tree replaced with NULL.
```

<sup>Created on 2022-08-12 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>